# Deleting entities with 0..1 to 1 relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

It's me and my EF problems again. I have successfully generated two entities with 0.1 to 1 relationship:

```
public class File
{
    [Key]
    public int FileId { get; set; }

    public virtual FileData FileData { get; set; }
}
public class FileData
{
    [Key]
    public int FileDataId { get; set; }

    public virtual File File { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

with the Fluent API definition of:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
            .HasOptional(x => x.FileData)
            .WithRequired(x => x.File)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

This generates my model and DB just fine. I can insert new data to both tables fine, but when I try to delete either one of the entities I get an error:

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: A primary key property that is a part of referential integrity constraint cannot be changed when the dependent object is Unchanged unless it is being set to the association's principal object. The principal object must be tracked and not marked for deletion.

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectConflicts(IList 1 entries)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet 1.Remove(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet 1.Remove(TEntity entity)
at ...
```

Notice that the exception is coming already from Remove, not from the actual SaveChanges.

**How am I supposed to delete the entities or what am I doing wrong when defining the relationship between the two entities?**

Comment: can you show the ef query for delete?

Comment: Something is wrong with the delete code, could you post it? The main question is where and how do you get the entity instance you are trying to delete.

Comment: Yeah, there is something fishy. I created the same scenario in a sample project (https://github.com/antsim/EntityFrameworkTester) and the removal works perfectly there. I guess it must be some other references that are interfering with the remove.